# Using a DatePicker as a parameter in datasource script builder,

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having trouble getting a DateBox that is populated with the current date on the onAttach event to update the query builder in my datasource. It works fine when a user selects a date but remains empty when the page loads.

Datasource Query Builder

```
expected_date = :expected
```

dateBox value:

```
@datasource.query.parameters.expected
```

onAttach - dateBox widget

```
widget.value = new Date();
widget.datasource.load();
```

DateBox onValueChange

```
widget.datasource.load();
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that the datasource query is running before I set the date in my dateBox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that you are actually running into concurrent executions, meaning you set your widget value in the onAttach event, the code immediately moves on to reloading the datasource and updating the binding on the widget at the same time, with one beating out the other. Things you could try instead of `widget.value = new Date()` for the widget onAttach is `widget.datasource.query.parameters.expected = new Date()` or you could bind the parameter in the datasource itself to the widget and then autoload the datasource. See if either of those work.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusMalessa. Unfortunately it's still behaving the same way. I tried both suggestions.

Comment: Solved it by using a query script to set the date if the parameter was not yet assigned.